# Do all ViewControllers run in the background when using TabBarContoller?

Tags: ios, background, locationmanager, multiple-instances, tabbarcontroller

If I use a TabBarController, and two of my ViewContollers access the GPS (LocationManager) when I switch from the VC1 to VC2, does VC1 run in the background (is the LocationManager active)?  If so, are any issues caused by having VC2s (visible) LocationManager running at the same time?

Comment: As long as your `tabbarcontroller` has memory, yeah all your `viewcontrollers` will be alive. You can start a service and can get updates while another vc is on screen.

Comment: OK, great!  Thank you.  I can infer then, that having both running at the same time does not adversely affect anything?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Your question is misleading. The phrase "run in the background" implies running on a background thread. That is different from a view controller doing work when it is not the front-most view controller. Yes, if you have a view controller create an instance of the location manager and start location updates, it will get those updates even if you push another view controller on top of it. However, those location updates methods will be called on the main thread, not on a background thread.

Comment: As Matt says in his answer, you should stop the location manager from sending updates to a view controller that isn't front-most. If you need to be doing global location tracking then you probably want to create your own singleton that subscribes to location updates, and have **it** notify the front view controller if that view controller needs updates.

Comment: OK, I believed I understand that I need to stop the location manager that is not on the topmost VC.  I created a Container VC to select between VC1 and VC2 with a segmented switch.  Do you know of a way to perform such as could probably be done with prepareForSegue (I think... I'm new at this) if I used direct segue link?  I really do apologize if I'm not being clear... this is new territory for me, and I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you again Matt and Duncan.  I think I found a simple work-around in my method to update (change) from VC1 to VC2 and reverse. Just before I remove the top and add the bottom to swap, I .stopUpdateingLocation to the old top and then after .startUpdatingLocation to the new top viewController.   Once again, I apologize for my lack of clarity (this is my first go at it), but very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it enough to use stopUpdatingLocation() or do I need to eliminate the location manager object created?

Answer (score 0):

> If so, are any issues caused by having VC2s (visible) LocationManager running at the same time?

Though it is not strictly forbidden to have multiple location manager instances, it is not wise policy to have multiple location managers operating simultaneously. You should be very careful here to stop the VC1 location manager when you leave VC1, and to stop the VC2 location manager when you leave VC2.